# Selection of objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

What is  the difference between selecting by $\binom{n}{2}$ and selecting by $\binom{n}{1}\cdot\binom{n-1}{1}$?

My reasoning for $\binom{n}{2}$ is selecting $2$ objects from $n$ objects. And for $\binom{n}{1}\cdot\binom{n-1}{1}$ is first selecting one object from $n$ objects then selecting one from remaining $(n-1)$ objects.

As the results are different, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Take for example $\{a,b,c\}$. Then, in $\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}$, you distinguish the cases : "taking $a$ first and then $b$" or "taking $b$ first and then $a$". Whereas, in $\binom{3}{2}$, you don't distinguish them. So taking $2$ different objects among $3$ is really $\binom{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are two distinct objects among those $n$ objects. If you first pick $a$ and then you pick $b$, you will get that same thing that you will get if you first pick $b$ and then pick $a$ (in both case, you will get $\{a,b\}$). And $\binom n2$ counts all *subsets* with $2$ elements of the set of those $n$ elements.

But if you want to take into account the *order* by which you have picked those objects, then $\binom n1\times\binom{n-1}1$ is the right formula, because then picking first $a$ and then $b$ is *not* the same thing as picking first $b$ and then $a$.